# CASE WHEN Menu based off of Routes.rb and Request.path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

I have a case when clause where based on the URL that you're at, it will bring in different menu options. However, depending on some of the menus that you could be at, it doesn't recognize that you have some variables assigned. The system errors:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Pages#users_page

Showing /home/initiald/RubymineProjects/SOWOnline/app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb where line #27 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"results", :action=>"show"}
```

Here is the code that I have so far

```
<% case request.path %>
  <% #ROOT AND SETTINGS %>
  <% when '/', settings_path, '/guest' %>
  <% #SURVEY AND RESULTS %>
  <% when '/sow_survey', '/surveys', '/results', result_path, results_path, available_surveys_path, take_survey_path, view_my_survey_path, edit_my_survey_path %>
    <% if permitted_to? [:admin, :partner, :employee], :users  %>
      <%= link_to 'new survey', available_surveys_path %>
      <%= link_to 'edit survey', results_path %>
    <% end %>
  <% #USERS %>
  <% when '/register' , '/users', '/sow_users', edit_user_path %>
      <% if permitted_to? [:admin, :partner, :employee], :users  %>
          <%= link_to 'new user', register_path %>
          <%= link_to 'list users', list_users_path %>
      <% end %>
  <% else %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any `result_path` without attributes, but there is `result_path(result_id)` path, which is:

```
{:controller=>"results", :action=>"show", :id => your_paticular_id}
```

and looks like

```
/results/:id
```

**UPD**

Just use regular expression here:

```
<% when '/sow_survey', '/surveys', '/results', /\/results\/\d*/, results_path, available_surveys_path, take_survey_path, view_my_survey_path, edit_my_survey_path %>
```

And yes - your code is messy.

Comment: The problem with it is that it works on the pages where result_path is used, but then it would error on something like edit_user_path(user) because in this instance, user is not defined.

Comment: Would it be better to use If Elsif statements instead or do you think I would run into the same issue of the variables not being defined?

Comment: use regular expression there `<% when '/sow_survey', '/surveys', '/results', /\/results\/\d*/, results_path, available_surveys_path, take_survey_path, view_my_survey_path, edit_my_survey_path %>
`

Comment: Thanks for the help fl00r. `'/\/results\/\d*/'` got rid of the errors and put the menu items in the places where they needed to be. For my own learning purposes, what does the `\/` prior to the results and the `\/\d*/` mean?

Comment: it is regular expression and it should be written without any quotes. http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/regexp.html